# Scalability / Performance of jBPM

Tags: jbpm

Need some help to understand what volumes can a jBPM  scale upto. In terms of business rules handling is there some benchmark study which I can refer to and helps me understand better how many instances would be required to say handle 100 tps.

Comment: See: https://developer.jboss.org/thread/211785